# A component is changing controlled i/p to be uncontrolled. This is caused by value changing from defined to undefined Decide between using controlled/

Tags: reactjs, axios

this is my login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Bottom";
// import { FaUser, FaUnlock } from "react-icons/fa";

const Login = () => {
  //functional component
  const [login, setLogin] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });
  // const [isSignUp, setisSignUp] = useState("");

  let user;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setLogin({ ...Login, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //reload the page

    if (login.username && login.password) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8080/api/registration/login", {
          username: login.username,
          password: login.password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
          user = response.data;
          console.log(user + "**********************");

          var usertype = response.data.usertype;
          console.log(usertype + "////////////");
          console.log(user + "*********");
          if (usertype === 1) return <Redirect to="/profile" />;
          // window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/profile";
          // console.log("Seller");
          else if (usertype === 0) return <Redirect to="/buyerprofile" />;
          // window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/buyerprofile";
          // console.log("Buyer");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
      setLogin({ username: "", password: "" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="font-awesome-4.7.0\css\font-awesome.min.css"
        />
      </head>
      <section className="vh-100">
        <div className="container h-100">
          <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div className="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
              <div className="card text-black" style={{ borderRadius: "25px" }}>
                <div className="card-body p-md-5">
                  <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 order-2 order-lg-1">
                      <p className="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">
                        Login
                      </p>

                      <form onSubmit={handleChange} className="mx-1 mx-md-4">
                        <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                          <i
                            class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                          ></i>
                          <div className="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="username"
                              name="username"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="User Name"
                              value={login.username}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            {/* {errors.username &&<p className="error">{errors.username}</p>} */}
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                          <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>{" "}
                          <div className="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                            <input
                              type="password"
                              id="password"
                              name="password"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Password"
                              value={login.password}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            {/* {errors.password &&<p className="error">{errors.password}</p>} */}
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                          <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                            onClick={handleSubmit}
                          >
                            Login
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">
                      <img/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

& if I try to login with my credentials it throws this error in console & this warning shows as soon as I start typing in input field

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.     at input
    at div
    at div
    at form
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at section
    at Login
```

I am new to react & I was trying my hands with react+sprinboot project, I saw some answers on uncontrolled input to controlled but here it's in-> reverse controlled input to uncontrolled,so what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the  handleChange function:

```
    setLogin({ ...Login, [name]: value });
```

i think you meant to write "login" and not "Login", the warning may be caused by that.

Comment: can't believe this was it...